# Libuser on Linux Mint Olivia

Tags: linux, linux-mint, libraries

I was wondering if anyone could help me in installing libuser on linux mint olivia.
I tried searching the apt-cache but could not find the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint Olivia is based on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail. The *libuser* package is in the **universe** repository of Ubuntu 13.04. There is a link to the Ubuntu 13.04 libuser webpage [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libuser&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all). If you have enabled the universe repository (it should be enabled by default), you can install libuser from the terminal by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libuser
```

Your `apt-cache` command will work if you have enabled the universe repository by running the command:

```
apt-cache show libuser
```

Or to display a list of libuser packages using a regular expression, use the command:

```
apt-cache search libuser*
```